# To check whether a digit is inside an integer (ruby)

Tags: ruby

Chinese people do not like numbers with a digit 4 in it. I am going to implement a membership program with membership numbers not including the digit 4, say:

```
number = 3
number.next.has4?
=> true
```

how the `has4?` method can be done (efficiently)?

** EDIT

Thanks for the answers, I performed simple benchmarking as a reference:

```
    class Fixnum
      def has4a?
        String(self).index('4') != nil
      end
    end

    class Fixnum
      def has4b?
        self.to_s[/4/]
      end
    end

    number = 3

    puts Time.now

    n = 0
    while n < 1000000
       number.next.has4a?
       n += 1
    end

    puts Time.now

    n = 0
    while n < 1000000
       number.next.has4b?
       n += 1
    end

    puts Time.now
```

the result on my PC shows `index` is faster than `regex`:

```
> ruby has4.rb
Tue May 11 18:36:04 +0800 2010
Tue May 11 18:36:05 +0800 2010
Tue May 11 18:36:11 +0800 2010
```

Edited below to include all 4 solutions, and make it easy to see duration of each:

```
class Fixnum
  def has4a?
    String(self).index('4') != nil
  end
end

class Fixnum
  def has4b?
    self.to_s[/4/]
  end
end

class Fixnum
  def has4c?
    temp = self
    while temp > 0
        if (temp % 10) == 4
            return true 
        end
        temp /= 10
    end
    false 
  end
end

class Fixnum
  def digits
    d, m = divmod(10)
    d > 0 ? d.digits + [m] : [m]
  end

  def has4d?
    self.digits.member?(4)
  end
end

before_A = Time.now

n = 0
has4 = 0
no4 = 0
while n < 5000000
   has4 += 1 if n.has4a? 
   no4  += 1 if !n.has4a?
   n    += 1
end

after_A = Time.now

puts after_A, has4, no4
puts "A duration: " + (after_A - before_A).to_s

before_B = Time.now

n = 0
has4 = 0
no4 = 0
while n < 5000000
   has4 += 1 if n.has4b? 
   no4  += 1 if !n.has4b?
   n    += 1
end

after_B = Time.now

puts after_B, has4, no4
puts "B duration: " + (after_B - before_B).to_s

before_C = Time.now

n = 0
has4 = 0
no4 = 0
while n < 5000000
   has4 += 1 if n.has4c? 
   no4  += 1 if !n.has4c?
   n    += 1
end

after_C = Time.now

puts after_C, has4, no4
puts "C duration: " + (after_C - before_C).to_s

before_D = Time.now

n = 0
has4 = 0
no4 = 0
while n < 5000000
   has4 += 1 if n.has4d? 
   no4  += 1 if !n.has4d?
   n    += 1
end

after_D = Time.now

puts after_D, has4, no4
puts "D duration: " + (after_D - before_D).to_s
```

result (ruby 1.8.7 (2009-06-12 patchlevel 174) [i486-linux] on Karmic).  Feel free to post data from other machines.

```
Tue May 11 16:25:38 -0400 2010
2874236
2125764
A duration: 35.375095
Tue May 11 16:26:19 -0400 2010
2874236
2125764
B duration: 40.659878
Tue May 11 16:27:38 -0400 2010
2874236
2125764
C duration: 79.12419
Tue May 11 16:31:28 -0400 2010
2874236
2125764
D duration: 229.573483
```

sorry for my previous typo and thanks Matthew Flaschen for fixing it. here's my benchmark:

```
    >ruby has4.rb
    Wed May 12 09:14:25 +0800 2010
    2874236
    2125764
    A duration: 18.186685
    Wed May 12 09:15:06 +0800 2010
    2874236
    2125764
    B duration: 40.388816
    Wed May 12 09:15:38 +0800 2010
    2874236
    2125764
    C duration: 32.639162
    Wed May 12 09:18:08 +0800 2010
    2874236
    2125764
    D duration: 150.024529

    >ruby -v
    ruby 1.8.7 (2010-01-10 patchlevel 249) [i386-mingw32]
```

Comment: Hahah what a hilarious implementation reason.

Comment: yeah, it's because the pronunciation of 四 (four) is similar to 死 (dead) in Chinese ;-)

Comment: I never really got that. The tones are different.

Comment: @Jon, you have to pronoun them in Mandarin to feel the similarity.

Comment: @Horace: I understand the similarity. It's just that there are a lot of "si" words and I don't know how this particular association happened.

Comment: According to Wikipedia ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_Security_number#Valid_SSNs ), SSNs aren't allowed to start with 666, so it's not an uncommon request.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
class Fixnum
  def has4?
    String(self).index('4') != nil
  end
end
```

Comment: It is ridiculously inefficient to use string manipulation for a numeric problem.

Comment: @Pedro, The efficiency of the human is paramount.  Only when the code is proven to be not fast enough should the machine's needs take precedence.

Comment: @Pedro, My version is fastest among those submitted on the OP's benchmark (after fixing it to call a different method every while loop, not `a` every time).  This is not at all surprising as both index and converting to string are both very common and therefore heavily optimized.  Next time, benchmark before you start making performance claims.

Comment: It's actually not all that uncommon that converting to a string is more efficient, especially for problems like this where we're looking for a specific digit. After the highly optimized string conversion, checking for a substring is much faster than performing division.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to do this mathematically without converting the number to a string, the following algorithm will work:

```
while num > 0
    if (num % 10) == 4
        return true
    num = num / 10
return false
```

Comment: this looks like python to me ;-)

Comment: +1 most efficient solution. I felt extreme radiation burns in my eyes when I read the string solutions. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349378/new-programming-jargon-you-coined/2444303#2444303

Comment: @Wilhelm, You may be surprised to learn that the string solution executes in about half the time.  I tested 1,000,000 random integers between 0 and 999,999; this took 6.6. seconds to ran.  The string solution (`to_s[/4/]`) took 2.9.

Comment: @WilhelmTell, this is the *least* efficient solution, except for Mladen's which I think was tongue in cheek.

Comment: @Wayne @Matthew ah. then there's more to the underlying mechanisms of Ruby than meet the eye. Either Ruby is extraordinarily smart about strings or (and) Ruby is extraordinarily dumb about integers. But I should have definitely been more cautious with my statements and assumptions.

Comment: @Wilhelm, it's definitely smart about strings.  They seem to be almost entirely [implemented in C](http://ruby-doc.org/doxygen/1.8.4/string_8c-source.html).  And my code only directly uses three Ruby methods.  In contrast, the above algorithm uses a long series of short Ruby methods (operators), which probably causes much of the overhead.  With a JIT like [Ludicrous](http://rubystuff.org/ludicrous/) the results might be different, since it might be able to automatically compile the Ruby into native code.

Answer (score 3):

something like

```
def has4?
  self.to_s[/4/]
end
```

?

Comment: converting a number to a string, and generating an automat with a regex is wonderfully efficient! (irony)

Comment: The `self.` can be left out, if you wish.

Answer (score 1):

If you dislike strings, but like recursion:

```
class Fixnum
  def digits
    d, m = divmod(10)
    d > 0 ? d.digits + [m] : [m]
  end
end

12093.digits
#=> [1, 2, 0, 9, 3]
1.digits
#=> [1]
115.digits.member?(4)
#=> false
145.digits.member?(4)
#=> true
```

:)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a different solution:  Use a simple one-up counter for your internal ids.  Then, when you want to show the user their id#, render it in base 9, swapping all 4s for 9s.

```
user_visible_id = internal_id.to_s(9).gsub('4','9').to_i
```

Then, when processing their information, you can get their internal id back just as easily:

```
internal_id = user_visible_id.to_s.gsub('9', '4').to_i(9)
```

This way generating internal ids is easy (you don't have to loop through generating and checking them until you get one without a 4).  If you wanted, you could wrap the oneup counter in a module, so that the rest of your application uses the `user_visible_id`, which will cut down on the confusion:

```
module IDGen
  @counter = 0
  def self.next
    @counter += 1
    @counter.to_s(9).gsub('4','9').to_i
  end
  def self.reset
    @counter = 0
  end
end

#...
User.new( IDGen.next )
```

Comment: I like this, except I would have the user-visible id always be treated as a string.  So it would be `user_visible_id = internal_id.to_s(9).gsub('4','9')` and `internal_id = user_visible_id.gsub('9', '4').to_i(9)`

Answer (score 0):

```
numbers.select{|number|!number.include?('4')}
```